# How to generate output to a folder in bash shell

Tags: bash, shell

I need to run a service and save all the output to a log folder with the timestamp as the log name. My code `start_service.sh` doesn't work. There is a folder `log` in the current location of `start_service.sh`.

```
nohup myservice >> "logs\$(date +'%Y%m%d%I%M%p').log" &
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be a forward slash `/`. And if the directory is named `log`, change `logs` to `log`.

```
nohup myservice >> "log/$(date +'%Y%m%d%I%M%p').log" &
```